# Unable to bind WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

This is my first time using TreeView Control in WPF application, and that became more difficult than I thought.

My TreeView has to be populated by MyGroup and MyList classes. MyGroup could have zero or several MyGroup children and one or several MyList children instances.

All the hierarchy is currently stored in one static MyGroup instance (RootGroup).

My goal is to bind this instance, since when RootGroup's children are modified, the treeview is updated.

To more the user could have the possibility to drag and drop groups and lists inside the TreeView to modify the hierarchy, and RootGroup will be updated too.

I have already read some tutorials about TreeViewControl, but I've never seen someone making an editable TreeView like this.

Do I need some ViewModel to do this ? 
Do you have examples about this kind of TreeView Control ?

EDIT: 
This is what I did, but nothing is shown in the TreeView.

```
public class VecViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
            }
        }
    }

public class VecGroup : VecViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<VecGroup> _groups;
        public ObservableCollection<VecGroup> Groups
        {
            get { return _groups; }
            set
            {
                _groups = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<VecList> _lists;
        public ObservableCollection<VecList> Lists
        {
            get { return _lists; }
            set
            {
                _lists = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Lists");
            }
        }

        public IList Children
        {
            get
            {
                var c = new CompositeCollection();
                c.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = Groups } );
                c.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = Lists });
                return c;
            }
        }
}
public class VecList : VecViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**MyTreeView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyTreeView : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<VecGroup> VecRoot;
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        VecRoot = new ObservableCollection<VecGroup>() { new VecGroup() { Name = "Test" } };
    }
}
```

**MyTreeView.xaml**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyTreeView/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding VecRoot}" x:Name="ExplorerView">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vec:VecGroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vec:VecList}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView >
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, do it with a viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project: [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/26288/simplifying-the-wpf-treeview-by-using-the-viewmode)
In this project, they are binding the TreeView and searching items inside it.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already read this post. I updated my question with my code to give you a better idea of my project, which has to use heterogeneous types data binding and also  drag and drop feature.